# Simulated Sharpe Ratio Calculation for Leveraged Portfolio

Tags: simulations, sharpe-ratio, log-returns, leverage, vba

I've written some VBA code to simulate the effect of borrowing money, investing it, and repaying the loan daily.

PseduoCode:

1. Start with a portfolio value of P = 1
2. Each day borrow P, invest 2*P, and get a lognormal return on double the portfolio.  Then repay (1+daily interest)*P.
3. Repeat for each trading day in the year
4. Repeat for numT trials
5. Calculate the mean and variance of excess returns for the trial results.  Use this to calculate a Sharpe Ratio.

I would expect that the Sharpe Ratio would be the same as the unleveraged Sharpe Ratio when borrowing at the risk-free rate and lower (higher) when borrowing at a higher (lower) rate.  However, I'm not matching the expected Sharpe Ratio.  I've tried calculating returns as arithmetic or as log, and neither has made me match.

Actual Code:

```
Sub margintest()
Dim x&, y&, numT&
Dim m#, my#, v#, vy#, p#, rf#, sum#, SqSum#

my = 0.08
vy = 0.5
rf = 0.03
m = my / 252
v = vy / 252 ^ 0.5
numT = 10000
Debug.Print "Expected Sharpe:" & (my - rf) / vy

For y = 1 To numT
    p = 1
    For x = 1 To 252
        p = 2 * p * Exp(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), m, v)) - p - p * rf / 252
    Next x
    sum = sum + p - 1 - rf
    'sum = sum + Log(p) - rf
    SqSum = SqSum + (p - 1 - rf) * (p - 1 - rf)
    'SqSum = SqSum + (Log(p) - rf) * (Log(p) - rf)
Next y
mean = sum / numT
Var = SqSum / numT - mean ^ 2
Sharpe = mean / Var ^ 0.5
Debug.Print "Mean:" & mean & ", Var:" & Var & ", Sharpe:" & Sharpe

End Sub
```

Results:
Expected Sharpe Ratio = (.08-.03)/.5=.1

Simulated Sharpe Ratios (Log Returns): -0.1461820, -0.1531049, -0.1427345
Simulated Sharpe Ratios (Arithmetic Returns): 0.2332556, 0.2367405, 0.2286082

How should the Sharpe Ratio be calculated and why is it not matching the expected ratio when borrowing at the risk-free rate?

Answer (score 1):

I have not fully gone through the logic of your investment process, but I think the term which you use to propagate the price from one timestep to the next is flawed:

Exp(WorksheetFunction.Norm_Inv(Rnd(), m, v))

This function generates Gaussian random numbers with mean $\mu t$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\sigma/252}$. What is missing in this is the $\sigma$ component in the  drift:

$S_{i+1}=S_{i} exp((\mu-0.5\sigma^{2})\delta t+\sqrt{\delta t}\sigma z)$

where z is a (0,1) normal random number. To fix this, you will have to adjust the definition of "my" in the VBA code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I also have not looked at your vba.
But the assumption that the leveraged portfolio sharpe ratio is the same as unleveraged book is INCORRECT and a flawed assumption.

Let the flames start. please google *Determinants of Levered Portfolio Performance* by Robert M. Anderson, Stephen W. Bianchi, Lisa R. Goldberg before flaming.

But its complicated beyond your code to simulate the feedback loop that causes this.